# Get metadata of storage file in Firebase

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase storage.
I have a function that lists all the files in that storage.
I download anything that doesn't exist locally, which is fine.

I want to get the metadata, particularly `last modified` information from the `Storage` for each file, so I can compare that to the locally downloaded file metadata and determine if it needs to be updated.

However, I can't make head nor tail of the Firebase documentation regarding this:

```swift
// Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
let storage = Storage.storage()

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
let storageRef = storage.reference()

// Create a reference to the file we want to download
let textRef = storageRef.child("/")
        
let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        
textRef.listAll { (result, error) in
    for item in result!.items {
```

From this point I want to get the metadata property for each `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
try {
        const bucketName = 'your-bucket-name';

        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucketName);
     const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();

      // Process the files as needed in the forEach loop
      files.forEach(async (file) => {
     // console.log('File:', file.name);
      await   file.getMetadata()
        .then(([metadata]) => {

     
        const fileLastModified = metadata.updated;
         console.log('File name:', file.name);
           console.log('Metadata:', metadata);
           console.log(file.name+ ': is queried successfully'+'and last modified on ->'+fileLastModified)
            res.status(200).send('file queried successfully');
  
})
    });

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error listing files metadata:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error Encountered');
      }
```

**EDIT: for swift**

```
func getLastUpdatedFilesMetadata() {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    
    let bucketRef = storageRef.child("your_bucket_name")
    
    bucketRef.listAll { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        let files = result.items
         for file in result.items {
            // Get the metadata for the file
            file.getMetadata { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error while getting metadata for file \(file.name): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                // geting the last modified timestamp for file
                if let lastModified = metadata?.updated {
                    print(" lastupdate timestamp for file \(file.name): \(lastModified)")
                } else {
                    print("lastupdate timestamp not available for file \(file.name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `res.status(200).json(metadata);` needs to be inside the `then` code block for this to work.

Comment: ooh i see thanks to notify

Comment: The question asks about getting metadata for multiple files (the result of listAll), and says nothing about using Express to return results.

Comment: thanks  i also missed to add for `const fileLastModified=metadata.updated`

Comment: Apologies late reply, been unable to get to computer. Thanks for replying but as Doug Stevenson wrote, I'm looking at getting metadata for the listAll items. Also, my code is in swift. Any further advice would be appreciated

Comment: Appreciated. Accepted answer

Comment: good to hear ,please edit the question and add `swift` tag to it because with the current tags and the word `function` it is hard to tell whether you are looking for `firebase functions`  or for `swift`